# react-scripts-ts results in corrupted build

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I am working on this legacy application. It is using react-scripts-ts for running it. So the scripts section of package.json looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build"
  },
```

I was cleaning some dependencies as they caused us an issue, but I am unable to get the application to work now.

If I do `npm start` all is good and works well.

If I do `npm run buil` all compiles ok no errors. However, if I try to use the application from the built artifacts I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at 6.fb2d1b96.chunk.js:1:99050
    at 6.fb2d1b96.chunk.js:1:99118
    at Object.e.exports (6.fb2d1b96.chunk.js:1:100445)
    ...
```

Would you have any pointers or tips on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful debugging switching version of `react-scripts-ts` to the latest sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code:
If you have `React.component` and replace it with `React.Component`.

That is what i can think of from first glance, otherwise you can provide us with code sample.

Edit: Another thing may be the imports, check them as well.

Ref:
https://medium.com/@anuhosad/react-errors-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or-a-function-4aac6e5173ad